# replacing '\\' string with '\' in java

Tags: java, regex

Hi we have a string like `"ami\\303\\261o"`. we want to replace `\\` with `\`.

We have tried the following:

1. `replace("\\", "\")`
2. `replaceAll("\\", "\")`

But we didn't get proper output.

Comment: Is `"ami\\303\\261o"` the "real" string or the string literal in Java ?

Comment: I assume in Java, ``\`` is the escape character, so ``\\`` will produce a literal backslash. So the string will actually only contain ``\``, not ``\\``. How exactly do you want the result to look like?

Comment: @FelixKling your edit seems to answer the question rather than fix the question. What's the story here?

Comment: @mah: All I did was adding backticks because the ``\`` where not rendered properly. I did not change the content of string or code (see the markdown side-by-side comparison).

Comment: The edit history standard view is very confusing here...

Comment: What's the output you get when you print your initial string?

Answer (score 3):

For use in a Java regex, you need to escape the backslashes twice:

```
resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("\\\\\\\\", "\\\\");
```

1. In a regex, `\\` means "a literal backslash".
2. In a Java string, `"\\"` encodes a single backslash.
3. So, a Java string that describes a regex that matches a single backslash is `"\\\\"`
4. And if you want to match two backslashes, it's `"\\\\\\\\"`, accordingly.

Comment: This. Is. Ugly. Is there a better way?

Comment: There is little reason to use `replaceAll` in this case - `replace` is much clearer.

Comment: @assylias: Certainly, but the OP specifically asked about a regex.

Answer (score 3):

You must keep backslash escaping in mind. Use

```
public class so {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "ami\\\\303\\\\261o";
        System.out.println(s);
        s = s.replace("\\\\", "\\");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
};
```

Each backslash escapes the following backslash and resolves to the two literal strings `\\` and `\`

Also keep in mind, [`String.replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) returns the modified string and keeps the original string intact.

Answer (score 3):

No need of regex here. Escape the slashes and use replace()

```
someString.replace('\\\\', '\\');
```

Comment: You should replace the `'` with `"`.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because the `\\` inside your input String get internally replaced by `\` because of the [Java Escape Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).
That means that if you output your String without performing any regex on it, it would look like this: `"ami\303\261o"`.

Generally you should remember to escape **every** escape-character with itself:

```
\ -> escaped = \\  
\\ -> escaped = \\\\  
\\\ -> escaped = \\\\\\  
...and so on
```

Comment: String expectedString="ami\303\261o"; its ouput is like: amiÃ±o
String str="ami\\303\\261o"; its output is like: ami\303\261o

we required String 'amiÃ±o'.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
 String val = "ami\\303\\261o"; 
    val =val.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\");        
    System.out.println(val);
```

Outpout would be

> ami\303\261o

A Fiddle is created here check it out

[Java Running Example](http://ideone.com/afgNgH)

Comment: The original string was the same, the replace does nothing here.

Comment: I tried and run the above program and added the output in the post

Comment: Try to run this code then:
`String val = "ami\\303\\261o"; System.out.println(val);`
The output is still `ami\303\261o`.

Comment: that is the answer OP is looking for. Ok I am adding more to post